# How do i preload images used with onmouseover/onmouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onmouseover

I have some simple jquery which needs to show corresponding css background images:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                console.log("ready!");
                var tmp_src;
                $('.home-slider li').mouseover(function() {
                    var src = $(this).find('a').attr('data-src');
                    console.log('src: ' + src);
                    $('.content-area').css('background-image', 'url(images/' + src + ')');
                    tmp_src = src;
                });
                $('.home-slider li').mouseout(function() {
                    console.log('src: ' + tmp_src);
                    $('.content-area').css('background-image', 'url(images/' + tmp_src + ')');
                });
            });
```

and the html part is like

```
<ul class="home-slider">
    <li><a href="#" data-src="test.jpg">Project 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="test2.jpg">Project 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="test3.jpg">Project 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I seems to work but i see a flickring, so how can i preload? Also what would be nice effect to smooth things out???

regards

Comment: _"how can i preload?"_ Like [this](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/). _"what would be nice effect to smooth things out?"_ [`$.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)?

Comment: I would include them on the page and if needed run replace with the fadeout effect

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this: run the jquery css command once for each image and apply it to an invisible div:

HTML

```
<ul class="home-slider">
  <li><a href="#" data-src="test.jpg">Project 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-src="test2.jpg">Project 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-src="test3.jpg">Project 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="preloadbox" style="display:none"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");

    // preload all images into invisible preloadbox div
    $('.home-slider li a').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('data-src');
        $('#preloadbox').css('background-image', 'url(images/' + src + ')');
        console.log(src + ' preloaded');
    });

    var tmp_src;
    $('.home-slider li').mouseover(function() {
         var src = $(this).find('a').attr('data-src');
         console.log('src: ' + src);
         $('.content-area').css('background-image', 'url(images/' + src + ')');
         tmp_src = src;
    });
    $('.home-slider li').mouseout(function() {
         console.log('src: ' + tmp_src);
         $('.content-area').css('background-image', 'url(images/' + tmp_src + ')');
    });
});
```

This approach won't slow down the rendering of the page since it runs once the DOM is ready.

Also: in your existing code be careful because `tmp_src` may not yet be defined on mouseout.

Comment: tx, had to add function() to  $('.home-slider li a').each({ so it reads  $('.home-slider li a').each(function(){

Answer (score 0):

When you bind the events, go ahead and preload the images upfront.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
    var tmp_src;
    // preload hover graphics
    $('.home-slider li a').each(function () {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = $(this).data('src');
    });
    $('.home-slider li')...
```

However, a better solution would be to use an image sprite and css hover rather than js events.